# Paypal integration with Braintree

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, braintree

I am trying to integrate braintree for payments in Nodejs and Javascript.

I have created an account on https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com and now I am trying to integrate my braintree payment with my website using "drop in" integration, I followed all the steps given on site, with which I get a paypal button, which on click opens up a paypal pop up window in which I enter my account details, After which it asks to agree on various terms. After clicking Agree it says :

**"Sorry we cannot connect to PayPal. Please try again in a few minutes. Try Again"**
I am not sure why I am getting this.

Looks like a problem of setting up my profile of Paypal with Braintree (though in sandbox it doesn't really matters). I tried to follow set up of paypal with braintree as instructed on braintree portal, but with no success I am still at the same Error Message.

Code used is from following Braintree documentation:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/guides/drop-in#paypal

Please help me out with this.

Comment: facing same issue. Python + JS ..... have you solved ????

Comment: same issue with Rails + JS, the `dropin` form works with their custom credit cards but the issue comes when you try login in the paypal it gives this error.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to contact braintrees support and they configured my sandbox account.

This is what they said:

> Hey Johhan,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to Braintree support. I’d be happy to help.
>
> I took a look at your Sandbox account and it looks like you weren’t
>   set up with a processor connection to test out PayPal. This can happen
>   sometimes when Sandbox accounts are created outside of the United
>   States.
>
> We have corrected this setting and your Sandbox is now set up to
>   process PayPal. You can verify that PayPal is a valid payment method
>   in your Sandbox by logging into your Sandbox Control Panel and
>   clicking on Settings > Processing. You’ll see a list of accepted
>   payment methods next to your Merchant Account.
>
> Hope that helps! Let us know if there’s anything else we can do for
>   you.
>
> Best,

Basically, you have to verify that PayPal is a valid payment method in your sandbox account.

Comment: support forward me to https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/php#linked-paypal-testing

Answer (score 7):

I contact their support team. this was their response

**"I believe you’re running into this issue because your sandbox was created in Pakistan, which is not a supported country with PayPal. If you are a developer working for a US based merchant on an integration, you will need to signup for a US sandbox account. You can do this on our website by selecting United States as your country using the drop down menu on the bottom left of the page"**

Remember: bottom left of signup page >> Select Country as US

i signed up for another sandbox account on Braintree using US as my country and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is true. I had a PH account and having trouble with integrating Paypal into my Sandbox. I created a US Sandbox account and it worked.