# Facing error sorry we cannot connect to PayPal in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, rubygems, spree, spree-paypal-express

I have an ecommerce-application in that I had integrated Paypal with braintree using

gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero', branch: ‘3-1-stable’
I have my Paypal sandbox account and included my credentials in my application.

[image]

Now when I go to checkout page <  select Paypal option < continue payment then I get following error :

[image]

Please help me out to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been answered on Github, I'm linking to issue.
https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero/issues/58

EDIT
To sum up, most likely it is caused by one of two things:
1. Address verification, try this one as a valid example:

`John
Doe
123 Billing Street
Apt. #1
Chicago
United States of America
Illinois
60618
555666555`

2. Braintree sandbox account has not been set to process PayPal (this can happen when an account is created from outside the U.S.).

You can verify that PayPal is a valid payment method in your Sandbox by clicking on `Settings > Processing`. You’ll see a list of accepted payment methods next to your Merchant Account ([Paypal integration with Braintree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494657/paypal-integration-with-braintree/31975591#31975591)).